I am Getting an error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
I am getting my this error as I am running by Kafka Application in Spring Boot. I want to create topic via running my application.
This is my config class:
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    NewTopic createTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("product-created-events-topic")
                .partitions(3)
                .replicas(3)
                .configs(Map.of("min.insync.replicas", "2"))
                .build();
    }
}

My application.properties:
spring.application.name=Product-Microservice
server.port=0
server.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092, localhost:9094
spring-kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring-kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

This is the Error shown in my kafka server:
[2024-06-17 09:45:17,355] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='product-created-events-topic', numPartitions=3, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='min.insync.replicas', value='2')]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.

When I changed replicas(3) to replicas(1), it is working and my topic is created:
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    NewTopic createTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("product-created-events-topic")
                .partitions(3)
                .replicas(1) //Changed from 3 -> 1
                .configs(Map.of("min.insync.replicas", "2"))
                .build();
    }
}

after running this my process was created but with only 1 replica
Topic: product-created-events-topic     TopicId: ---- PartitionCount: 3       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: min.insync.replicas=2
        Topic: product-created-events-topic     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: product-created-events-topic     Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: product-created-events-topic     Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0

I am using windows so I am using traditional kafka with zookeeper


using windows so I am using traditional kafka with zookeeper

You'll need to start 3 brokers on your machine to create any topics with 3 replicas. This means executing kafka-server-start multiple times, or using Docker Compose / minikube with 3 brokers

Can you tell me how to start multiple broker? Should I start 3 kafka servers or change something in server.properties file? Actually I am fairly new to kafka and am following a tutorial to learn it, there he didn't make any changes so I reckoned that it could be shortcoming of using zookeeper (as MAC uses KRaft). It would be greate if you help me.

Windows should be able to use Kraft as well. As mentioned, you'd run kafka-server-start several times with separate properties files... Using multiple brokers on one machine is not recommended, however. One hard drive is a single point of failure, so no point in replicating, really

Okay thank you for your help. BTW we can run KRaft in windows in WSL(Linux in windows)
